# Python script is not writing to disk

Tags: python, file-io

I am trying to write a little script which grabs link from a rss-feedreader and writes them into a text file.

The strange thing is it was working yesterday and is still working when I start it by clicking on it or in the console, but not when it is started from the rss-reader.

Well it's basically working even when started form the rss-reader, but it won't write to the file, although I get the "succes notification" and no errors!

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys  # getting the passed arguments
import time
from gi.repository import Notify  # display a notification
import datetime

# generating the file name
year = str(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[0])
week = str(datetime.date.today().isocalendar()[1])

# adds a leading zero if week is < 10
if len(week) < 2:
    week = '0' + week

grabbed = 'news_' + year + '_kw_' + week

try:
    url = sys.argv[1] + '\n'
    # success notification
    topic = 'Grabbed and written to KW ' + week
except IndexError:
    url = 'Error: ' + 'No link received! ' + time.strftime("%Y.%m.%d - %H:%M:%S") + '\n'
    # display a error notification
    topic = "Grabbing failed :("

try:
    file = open("test.txt", "a")
    file.write(url)
    file.close()
except IOError:
    topic = 'Error:'
    url = 'File was not written!'

# display the notification
Notify.init("Notification")
Hello = Notify.Notification.new(topic, url, "dialog-information")
Hello.show()
```

I tried different rss-readers and as I said it was working yesterday but not today anymore.

(I am running Linux)

And I am starting it from the rss-reader by changing the "open with external browser" field to "/path/to/my/script/grabber.py %u" So every click on a link will start it.

Comment: Are you sure it's not writing test.txt to some place you're not looking?  I'd be inclined to put a full path in there to where you want test.txt to be, to make sure.

Comment: I do not know what an rss-reader is but considering it to be somekind of a browser like thing. Make sure your application has write privileges on the directory you are creating the file in.

Comment: If he didn't have write priviledges, then the thing should generate an exception, rather than a success, I think?

Comment: @ GreenAsJade: THANK YOU!

I performed a search for the test.txt file and you are right, it is getting written somewhere else! (to my home directory) Really strange and I don't understand why it wrote the links yesterday to the right file?!
So I am going to change the path.